# How to reset jQuery variable based on selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created an HTML rubric that allows a user to select a cell and have it add up the earned points versus the points possible.  Right now, I have a function that only allows one `td` per row to be selected.  When a cell is selected, it adds the points to a variable.  The issue is, when I change the selection for the row, it just adds the new selection on top of the variable, it doesn't subtract and replace the value.

For example, if I had an 8 point selection made, but change it to 6, instead of the variable value being 6, it adds the 6 to the 8.

The function I have to add up the points is as follows:

```
jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded td.choice').click(function () {
    // Obtain points earned
    var ndx = jQuery(this).index() + 1;
    var target = jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded thead tr.points th:nth-child('+ndx+')').html();
    if(!isNaN(target) && target.length != 0) {
        pointsEarned += parseFloat(target);
    }
    jQuery('#ldrm-points-earned').html('Points Earned: '+pointsEarned);
    alert(pointsEarned);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6u2pjgu/1/

Any ideas on how I could alter the function to replace the value instead of adding on to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier if you use a single handler like

```
var total = 0,
    $headers = jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded thead tr.points th');
jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded td.choice').click(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this),
        $prev;
    if (!$this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $prev = $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');

        if ($prev.length) {
            total -= +$headers.eq($prev.index()).html() || 0;
        }
        total += +$headers.eq($this.index()).html() || 0;

        $this.addClass('selected');
        jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        var trackChanges = jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded').clone().html();
        jQuery('#ldrm_assignment_content').val(trackChanges);


        jQuery('#ldrm-points-earned').html('Points Earned: ' + total);
        alert(total);
    } //else don't do anything since it is already selected

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hamd16xj/)

---

If you want to retain your code structure

```
jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded td.choice').click(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this),
        $tr = $this.closest('tr'),
        prevValue = $tr.data('selected') || 0;

    // Obtain points earned
    var ndx = $this.index() + 1;
    var value = +jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded thead tr.points th:nth-child(' + ndx + ')').html() || 0;
    pointsEarned -= prevValue;
    pointsEarned += value;

    $tr.data('selected', value)
    jQuery('#ldrm-points-earned').html('Points Earned: ' + pointsEarned);
    alert(pointsEarned);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f6u2pjgu/4/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple fix.  Right now you have `pointsEarned += parseFloat(target);`.  Change that to simply `pointsEarned = parseFloat(target);`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/f6u2pjgu/2/

Comment: Right, that displays the correct value for the specific row, but now I need it to add up all the rows correctly!

Comment: So in the fiddle example, if all 4 rows have the 8 pt selection made, the total should be 32 points.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea to separate the calculation from the actual event handling.

To help with this, you could calculate the points per column beforehand:

```
var pointsPerColumn = $('#ldrm-rubric-loaded tr.points th').map(function() {
    return +$(this).text();
});
```

Then, write a small function that calculates the points earned on-the-fly; it uses the earlier `pointsPerColumn` variable for each selected cell and returns the sum:

```
function pointsEarned(sel)
{
    var total = 0;
    $(sel).find('td.choice.selected').each(function() {
        total += pointsPerColumn[$(this).index()];
    });
    return total;
}
```

Then, your click handler becomes quite simple:

```
jQuery('#ldrm-rubric-loaded td.choice').click(function () {
    alert(pointsEarned('#ldrm-rubric-loaded'));
});
```

```js
function addHandlers($cubric, $target) {
  var pointsPerColumn = $cubric.find('tr.points th').map(function() {
    return +$(this).text();
  });

  function pointsEarned() {
    var total = 0;
    $cubric.find('td.choice.selected').each(function() {
      total += pointsPerColumn[$(this).index()];
    });
    return total;
  }

  $cubric
    .find('td.choice')
    .click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

      $target.val($cubric.clone().html());
    })
    .click(function() {
      alert(pointsEarned());
    });
}

jQuery(function($) {
  addHandlers($('#ldrm-rubric-loaded'), $('#ldrm_assignment_content'));
});
```

```css
#ldrm-rubric-loaded {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#ldrm-rubric-loaded .ldrm tr.remove {
  display: none;
}
#ldrm-rubric-loaded .ldrm tr.points th:first-child {
  display: none;
}
#ldrm-rubric-loaded .ldrm tbody tr td:first-child {
  display: none;
}
#ldrm-rubric-loaded .choice {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#ldrm-rubric-loaded .choice.selected {
  background: #d1e0be;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ldrm-rubric-loaded">

  <table class="ldrm" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr class="remove">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><span class="btn"></span>
        </th>
        <th><span class="btn"></span>
        </th>
        <th><span class="btn"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="points">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th class="rb-top">8</th>
        <th class="rb-top">6</th>
        <th class="rb-top">4</th>
        <th class="rb-top">2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="rb-left">Category</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="btn"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="rb-left">Category</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="btn"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="rb-left">Category</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="btn"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="rb-left">Category</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
        <td class="choice">Enter the details of how to earn this amount of points!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```